# React not fetching data anymore

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, hibernate, react-hooks, react-router

Hi there I'm fairly new to react and I'm trying to create a student management app with React as a frontend and i can't seem to get the page to return a list of students since I tried working with the functions `useHistory` and `useNavigate` from react-router-dom to try redirect to an individual student component but I was unable to get them working on my project so I removed them.

The page was rendering the student objects from the backend API i created just fine before I tried implementing the two functions but now won't render any student object, all that is displayed are the table heads but not the table rows any help on what the problem would be appreciated

here is my hook component to fetch data before using `useHistory` & `useNavigate`

```js
function GetAllStudents() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = async () => {
    StudentService.getStudents() //axios service function used to fetch data
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        const currentStudent = res.data;
        setStudents(currentStudent); // try setStudents(res.data) if fails
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    // fetchData();
  };

  useEffect(() => fetchData(), []);

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form container p-4">
        <h1>Week 10 - React Frontend </h1>
        <a href="/add" class="btn btn-success">
          Add Student
        </a>
      </div>

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {students.map((student) => (
            <tr key={student.id}>
              <td> {student.firstname} </td>
              <td> {student.lastname}</td>
              <td> {student.email}</td>
              <td>
                <button className="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                <button
                  style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  onclick="return confirm('Do you Really want to delete')">
                  Delete{' '}
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GetAllStudents;
```

When I inspect elements on my browser it shows the state is not saving the objects to the array [image: React console log of component]

I don't know what I misconfigured because even when I change the function to a class component that also previously worked properly doesn't display the objects anymore

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StudentService from '../services/StudentService';

class GetAllStudents extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      students: [],
    };
    this.addStudent = this.addStudent.bind(this);
    this.editStudent = this.editStudent.bind(this);
    this.deleteStudent = this.deleteStudent.bind(this);
  }

  deleteStudent(id) {
    StudentService.deleteStudent(id).then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        students: this.state.students.filter((student) => student.id !== id),
      });
    });
  }
  updateStudent(id) {
    this.props.history.push(`/students/${id}`); // props(parameter) to navigate to edit student component
  }
  editStudent(id) {
    this.props.history.push(`/edit/${id}`); // props(parameter) to navigate to edit student component
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    StudentService.getStudents().then((res) => {
      this.setState({ students: res.data }); //loads all students in database
    });
  }

  addStudent() {
    this.props.history.push('/add'); //function to navigate to edit student component with form to add student
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form container p-4">
          <h1>Week 10 - React Frontend </h1>
          <a href="/add" class="btn btn-success">
            Add Student
          </a>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.students.map((student) => (
              <tr key={student.id}>
                <td> {student.firstname} </td>
                <td> {student.lastname}</td>
                <td> {student.email}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => this.updateStudent(student.id)}
                    className="btn btn-info">
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
                    onClick={() => this.deleteStudent(student.id)}
                    className="btn btn-danger"
                    onclick="return confirm('Do you Really want to delete')">
                    Delete{' '}
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GetAllStudents;
```

when I check my backend it shows calls are being made to the server [image] but react isn't fetching or displaying data

any help on how to solve this problem would be appreciated as I currently don't know what I did wrong

Comment: What's the response from the  StudentService.getStudents() call? is it returning what you expected?

Comment: @ShatteredDev thanks a lot i queried my database(mysql) and found all objects had been deleted...although i don't know how(I'll have to find the cause if the problem persists) It is now working, i'm currently unable to now add new student objects through the frontend but i think i might be able to reconfigure to work i'll repost the question if i fail to get it working